# Using Var results for next task

Tags: ansible

I have a var output in pastebin https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/3tzVPm6D, i want to access the highlighted values in it, the below yaml is correct to achieve that? i keep getting error like

```
{"failed": true, "msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'files'
```

> ```
>  win_service:
>   name: "{{item.filename.split('.')[0]}}"
>   path: "{{item.path}}" 
>   #state: absent     
>  with_items:
>      - "{{exepath.results.files}}"
> ```

Comment: Your approach is incorrect. Do you need only highlighted values (single file) or ever file from `files` from every result from `results`?

Comment: every file from files, basically i am collecting this from previous task

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `with_subelements` construction, as [described in documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements).

In your case it might be something like

```
win_service:
  name: "{{ item.1.filename.split('.')[0] }}"
  path: "{{ item.1.path }}"
  #state: absent
with_subelements:
   - "{{ exepath.results }}"
   - files
```

To quickly test result you may use `debug` module like

```
- debug: msg='{{ item.1.path }} {{ item.1.filename }}'
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ exepath.results }}"
    - files
```

You might also want to use `no_log: True` to suppress enormous amount of logging.

**Edit:**
to access only *exact* highlighted values you don't even need to iterate over subelements.

```
win_service:
  name: "{{ exepath.results[0].files[0].filename.split('.')[0] }}"
  path: "{{ exepath.results[0].files[0].path }}"
```

Comment: wow, this worked, however, it picked everytime the same thing and tried doing the task again

Comment: Check your dataset, it contains similar filename and path attributes for all elements.

Comment: yeah , but is there a way to pick only that?

Comment: updated to show exact match, however hardcoding dictionary sctructure in a role sounds like a bad idea in future, if data has any chance to be changed.

Comment: thanks for jumping in, however i dont understand on how to pick the exact list from the results, you have any url which explains that?